# VGA Output From ipad

Tags: iphone

Does apple support mirroring of ipad on tv can any one give me some idea

Answer (score 1):

**Read [this article](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/06/01/ipad-vga-output):**

> There’s been a lot of confusion about how the [iPad VGA Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC552ZM/A) works. I received mine today, and I thought I’d try to clear things up a little (and give you some code to play with, if you’re an iPad developer with a VGA adapter of your own).
>
> The first thing to understand is that the adapter does not mirror your iPad screen. You can’t plug your iPad into your TV or monitor and see all your apps on the big screen, like Steve Jobs does when he’s giving a demo.
>
> Apps that want to support external display via the adapter must explicitly do so; the developer has to write code to support it. There are some standard iPhone OS-supplied APIs which will automatically do the right thing (such as video playback via standard controllers), but generally you won’t see anything on your external display unless the app you’re using has taken steps to put something there. That’s the “bad” (though surely not surprising) news.
>
> The good news is that it’s trivially easy to support external display from your app if you’re a developer; the connected display just shows up as another UIScreen object. I made a sample project (which you can [download as a zip archive here](http://mattgemmell.com/files/source/ipad_vga_output.zip)) that shows how to do it.
>
> It’s basically just a nib with two windows (one for showing on the iPad, and one for showing on the connected external display), and a tiny bit of code to make it work.